# import cvs into postgres with python script

Tags: python, postgresql, ip-address

I am trying to import a CSV file of IP addresses into Postgres via python script. This is what I am at
[Python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLPEg.png)

since this is for testing. this is how test csv file is. [CSV FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2X0j.png)

Also this is the error I am getting
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZYGK.png)

I ran same python script with text file, same error.
Also, I tried manually uploading the same file via pgadmin. No issue. so its probably something I am missing in my code.
Also, i am able to connect to DB as in the screenshot above so not connection issue for issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ip_list is the filename not a list of IP addresses read from that file. The "i" value comes from calling executemany() on the filename string value which is expecting an iterable variable.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You do not open anywhere the actual file. You are trying to iterate over the file name.

You need to read the file lines and pass those lines into `execute`/`execute_many`.

Sample code:

```
import csv    
with open("test.csv", "r") as my_file:
    
        readers = csv.reader(my_file)
    
        for line in reader:
    
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO x(y) VALUES (%s)", line)
            cur.commit()
```